# Javascript cross-origin exception on Chrome but not on Firefox

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, cross-domain-policy

I recently developed a Firefox extension which allows me to automate some actions on several websites (mainly retrieving data).

The extension works well so I'm currently developing a Chrome version of the extension.

There are some differences between Chrome and Firefox extensions but it's mainly the same code which is running in both extensions.

---

**Issue**

Most of it works, however I'm having troubles with a specific website which works well with the Firefox extension.

On this website, I'm trying to get a table which is located into an iframe itself located into another iframe.

When accessing second iframe, I'm facing the following exception.

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://subdomain.domain.fr" from accessing a frame with origin "https://subdomain.domain.fr". The frame requesting access set "document.domain" to "domain.fr", but the frame being accessed did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access
```

The page is structured as follow

```
<iframe id="iframe_centrale" src="/[...]">
    [...]
    <iframe id="iframe" src="/[...]">
        [...]
        <table></table>
        [...]
    </iframe>
    [...]
</iframe>
```

And I'm trying to access the iframe as follow

```
var tableElement = null;
var iframe = null;
iframe = document.getElementById('iframe_centrale');
if(null != iframe)
{
    iframe = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("iframe");
    if(null != iframe)
    {
        tableElement = iframe.contentWindow.document.evaluate("//table", iframe.contentDocument, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
        if((null != tableElement)
        {
            // Read table
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Issue analysis**

The fired exception is usually met when trying to access a ressource located on another domain.

However in my case, both iframes are located on the same domain because the `src` attribute is a relative url.

The fact that the exact same code is working correctly with Firefox also confirms that I can access the second iframe.

---

**More information**

Another error I'm facing is that during the browsing process, I fill a form located into an iframe and the following exception is triggeredonce, however the form is still filled correctly.

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://subdomain.domain.fr" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

since its in a mutation observer loop, the instruction may work the second time, it could explain why the form is filled.

After filling the form, I click a button, into an iframe, itself into an iframe.
When the button is clicked I have the following exception

```
Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution
```

Once again, the click is made into a mutation observer loop so it may be triggered once, and then works, but I'm redirected to the next page so the click is working.

---

**Investigating from Firefox**

Since I can access both iframes' content from Firefox, I tried to print 'domain' and 'url' information for base document and both iframes.

```
#############################################################
### BASE PAGE : domain.fr / https://subdomain.domain.fr/path1
### IFRAME 1 : domain.fr / https://subdomain.domain.fr/path2
TypeError: iframe2 is null

[...]

#############################################################
### BASE PAGE : domain.fr / https://subdomain.domain.fr/path1
### IFRAME 1 : domain.fr / https://subdomain.domain.fr/path2
### IFRAME 2 : domain.fr / about:blank

[...]

#############################################################
### BASE PAGE : domain.fr / https://subdomain.domain.fr/path1
### IFRAME 1 : domain.fr / https://subdomain.domain.fr/path2
### IFRAME 2 : subdomain.domain.fr / https://subdomain.domain.fr/path3
```

So I think the issue is occurring because the second iframe changes its domain when the url is updated from `about:blank` to `https://subdomain.domain.fr/path3`

---

**Questions**

Why are exceptions fired with iframes located on the same domain/subdomain ?

Is there another way to access the second iframe content and act on it with Chrome ?

Does somebody knows why this code is working with Firefox but not with Chrome ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is stated in the error message:

```
The frame requesting access set "document.domain" to "domain.fr", but the frame being
accessed did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access
```

Same Origin Policy is based on the "[tuple origin](https://csplite.com/csp169/#tuple-origin)" term: `scheme` + `host` + `port` + `domain`. Origins are generally immutable, only the domain of a tuple origin can be changed, and only through the `document.domain` API (a port number will be additionally reset to **null**).

One of your frame with origin `https://subdomain.domain.fr:443` sets the `document.domain` property to the `https://domain.fr:null`.
To allow it to have access to other iframes on the page, you have to set `document.domain = "https://domain.fr"` to all ot them. Or if it possible [do not touch](https://csplite.com/csp/test344/#results) `document.domain` property at all for any iframe and main window.

It's somewhat strange why your code works in Firefox and doesn't work in Chrome - recent versions of both browsers support `document.domain` property the same way.

Pls **note** that `document.domain` property [is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain), so is better to avoid using it if possible.

> `Refused to run the JavaScript URL`

Looks like a Content Security Policy blocks the `<a href='void(0)'>` constructions. It does not prevent link following, just block an javascript execution.